# Hibernate/JPA cache lookup values

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching

We have JPA entities representing lookup values (states, country codes, etc). Methods that are called frequently to get `List`s of these values are cached using the `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable` annotation where appropriate.

We also have entities that have relationships with these lookup entities defined like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Address")
public class AddressEntity {
    // ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATE_CD", referencedColumnName = "CD")
    @NotNull
    private StateEntity state;
    // ...
}
```

When we load one of these entities and then call the getter on the associated lookup, Hibernate hits the database again to load that value. We'd like to make it so when we have an address and we do a `getState` on that address, we hit a local cache for that information. How can we do that with Hibernate/JPA?

```
// Get address:
Address address = addressRepo.findOne(addressId);

// Get the state - this causes an additional query to hit the database:
State state = address.getState();
```

Comment: You'll probably have to work with Hibernate's 2nd level cache for that, instead of Spring's general caching mechanism.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question: isn't this just a simple problem of lazy fetching a relationship causing hibernate to hit db again?

Comment: @Kayaman, yes, that sounds right. I'll have to take a look. We only want certain entities to be cached.

Comment: @Zeromus, yes, this is a lazy loading problem but one where we want certain lazily loaded entities to be cached by Hibernate so they aren't loaded from the db after the first time they are. We also want to control how that cache behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fetch type does not matter here. Hibernate's second-level cache behavior is to cache the ids of to-one association targets rather than the targets themselves.

Why not make `StateEntity` itself `@Cacheable`? It seems a very good candidate, as there should be (much) fewer instances of `StateEntity` than `AddressEntity`